# How to create a 3D graph from two 2D graphs

Tags: calculus, geometry, graphing-functions

I have an equation in the x-y plane, and another in the z-x plane.

Is it at all possible to combine them into the x-y-z space?

I realize that there might not be enough data to fill the gaps, but I thought of using one of many interpolation methods out there to fill the data (if needed)

Comment: Are they in the form $x=\dots$, $y=\dots$ or $z=\dots$?

Comment: One option is to treat your equations as *cylinders* (in the technical sense), and let your 3-d curve be the intersection between the cylinders.

Comment: It is best to provide an example. If you have an equation like y=x, and there is no Z axis variables, then you will still get 2-d curve.

Comment: Apparently there is some confusion about my notion.  For eg:  1st graph is y =a + b/x + exp(cx+d). The 2nd is z = (ex+f)/(gx+h)+i.   How would i go about making a three axis plot (3d) with this?     Ps:  on mobile, no access to pc.  Appologies.

Answer (score 2):

For this answer, I'll assume that your equations can be put in the form $y = f(x)$ and $z = g(x)$. If not, then the following doesn't apply.

With that assumption, then there is a very natural way to build a curve in 3-d based on your 2-d curves. In three dimensions, the curve $y = f(x)$ actually defines a *cylinder*, which is just what you get if you 'expand' the curve in the $z$ direction. Similarly, the $z = g(x)$ curve defines a cylinder that expands into the $y$ direction.

The intersection of those two cylinders will be a curve that exists in 3-dimensional space. Its coordinates are quite straightforward too; it will just pass through all the points $(x, f(x), g(x))$.